# Removing Unnecessary Negative Space from Dot Graph in Graphviz

Tags: graphviz, dot, graphing, erd

I am trying to use Graphviz to graph an ER diagram using dot. I have the following:

```
digraph ERD {
graph [ rankdir = "LR" ];
ranksep=1;
"DEPARTMENT" [ label="<DEPARTMENT> DEPARTMENT|<PK_DEPARTMENT>deptcode \l | <F_DEPARTMENT> self* \ldeptcode \ldeptname \l " shape = "record", style = "rounded" ];
"COURSE" [ label="<COURSE> COURSE|<PK_COURSE>cnum \l | <F_COURSE> self* \lcnum \lcname \ldepartment* \l " shape = "record", style = "rounded" ];
"PROFESSOR" [ label="<PROFESSOR> PROFESSOR|<PK_PROFESSOR>pnum \l | <F_PROFESSOR> self* \lpnum \lpname \loffice \ldepartment \l " shape = "record", style = "rounded" ];
"CLASS" [ label="<CLASS> CLASS|<PK_CLASS>term \l | <F_CLASS> self* \lcourse* \lterm \lsection \lprofessor* \l " shape = "record", style = "rounded" ];
"ENROLLMENT" [ label="<ENROLLMENT> ENROLLMENT|<PK_ENROLLMENT> | <F_ENROLLMENT> self* \lstudent* \lclass* \l " shape = "record", style = "rounded" ];
"SCHEDULE" [ label="<SCHEDULE> SCHEDULE|<PK_SCHEDULE>time \l | <F_SCHEDULE> self* \lclass* \lday \ltime \lroom \l " shape = "record", style = "rounded" ];
"MARK" [ label="<MARK> MARK|<PK_MARK>grade \l | <F_MARK> self* \lenrollment* \lgrade \l " shape = "record", style = "rounded" ];
"STUDENT" [ label="<STUDENT> STUDENT|<PK_STUDENT>snum \l | <F_STUDENT> self* \lsnum \lsname \lyear \l " shape = "record", style = "rounded" ];

"COURSE":"F_COURSE"->"DEPARTMENT":"PK_DEPARTMENT" [arrowhead = normal] [label="generic label"];
"PROFESSOR":"F_PROFESSOR"->"DEPARTMENT":"PK_DEPARTMENT" [arrowhead = normal] [label="generic label"];
"CLASS":"F_CLASS"->"COURSE":"PK_COURSE" [arrowhead = normal] [label="generic label"];
"ENROLLMENT":"F_ENROLLMENT"->"CLASS":"PK_CLASS" [arrowhead = normal] [label="generic label"];
"SCHEDULE":"F_SCHEDULE"->"CLASS":"PK_CLASS" [arrowhead = normal] [label="generic label"];
"MARK":"F_MARK"->"ENROLLMENT":"PK_ENROLLMENT" [arrowhead = normal] [label="generic label"];
}
```

However, the dot engine places the nodes such that there is an excessive amount of negative/white space in the graph. It ends up looking like this:

[image: ER_Diagram]

For example, the PROFESSOR table could have easily been placed above the COURSE table to save on space. A similar optimization could have been made with the SCHEDULE table. Additionally, the DEPARTMENT table could have been placed on the left of COURSE and PROFESSOR, rather than the right.

From reading about this on the internet, I came across possibly setting the rankdir. However, I think I need it to be LR because otherwise the nodes themselves are oriented sideways...

Is there any way to allow the arrows to go in both directions (not just from left to right, or vice versa?) to save on space? Or some other attributes I could specify to minimize the amount of unnecessary negative/white space my graph has? I don’t want to make the nodes, font, or arrow lengths smaller though.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should pay around a bit with `rank=same` like

```
digraph ERD {
graph [ rankdir = "LR" ];
ranksep=1;
"DEPARTMENT" [ label="<DEPARTMENT> DEPARTMENT|<PK_DEPARTMENT>deptcode \l | <F_DEPARTMENT> self* \ldeptcode \ldeptname \l " shape = "record", style = "rounded" ];
"COURSE" [ label="<COURSE> COURSE|<PK_COURSE>cnum \l | <F_COURSE> self* \lcnum \lcname \ldepartment* \l " shape = "record", style = "rounded" ];
"PROFESSOR" [ label="<PROFESSOR> PROFESSOR|<PK_PROFESSOR>pnum \l | <F_PROFESSOR> self* \lpnum \lpname \loffice \ldepartment \l " shape = "record", style = "rounded" ];
"CLASS" [ label="<CLASS> CLASS|<PK_CLASS>term \l | <F_CLASS> self* \lcourse* \lterm \lsection \lprofessor* \l " shape = "record", style = "rounded" ];
"ENROLLMENT" [ label="<ENROLLMENT> ENROLLMENT|<PK_ENROLLMENT> | <F_ENROLLMENT> self* \lstudent* \lclass* \l " shape = "record", style = "rounded" ];
"SCHEDULE" [ label="<SCHEDULE> SCHEDULE|<PK_SCHEDULE>time \l | <F_SCHEDULE> self* \lclass* \lday \ltime \lroom \l " shape = "record", style = "rounded" ];
"MARK" [ label="<MARK> MARK|<PK_MARK>grade \l | <F_MARK> self* \lenrollment* \lgrade \l " shape = "record", style = "rounded" ];
"STUDENT" [ label="<STUDENT> STUDENT|<PK_STUDENT>snum \l | <F_STUDENT> self* \lsnum \lsname \lyear \l " shape = "record", style = "rounded" ];

"COURSE":"F_COURSE"->"DEPARTMENT":"PK_DEPARTMENT" [arrowhead = normal] [label="generic label"];
"PROFESSOR":"F_PROFESSOR"->"DEPARTMENT":"PK_DEPARTMENT" [arrowhead = normal] [label="generic label"];
"CLASS":"F_CLASS"->"COURSE":"PK_COURSE" [arrowhead = normal] [label="generic label"];
"ENROLLMENT":"F_ENROLLMENT"->"CLASS":"PK_CLASS" [arrowhead = normal] [label="generic label"];
"SCHEDULE":"F_SCHEDULE"->"CLASS":"PK_CLASS" [arrowhead = normal] [label="generic label"];
"MARK":"F_MARK"->"ENROLLMENT":"PK_ENROLLMENT" [arrowhead = normal] [label="generic label"];

{rank=same STUDENT PROFESSOR SCHEDULE MARK}
}
```

Resulting in:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for that tip. I don't think this graph really resembles an ER diagram because the nodes are not evenly spaced, and there is still a lot of whitespace for the DEPARTMENT node. Would it be possible to allow arrows to go from right to left as well? Then maybe the DEPARTMENT node could be placed under the ENROLLMENT node to save on space...

Comment: Did you try a similar trick with `rank=same` (looks like it works out of the box)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind some tweaking, you could add some invisible edges and weight instructions. Commented code:

```
digraph ERD {
graph [ rankdir = "LR" ];
ranksep=1;
"DEPARTMENT" [ label="<DEPARTMENT> DEPARTMENT|<PK_DEPARTMENT>deptcode \l | <F_DEPARTMENT> self*    \ldeptcode \ldeptname \l " shape = "record", style = "rounded" ];
"COURSE" [ label="<COURSE> COURSE|<PK_COURSE>cnum \l | <F_COURSE> self* \lcnum \lcname \ldepartment* \l " shape = "record", style = "rounded" ];
"PROFESSOR" [ label="<PROFESSOR> PROFESSOR|<PK_PROFESSOR>pnum \l | <F_PROFESSOR> self* \lpnum \lpname \loffice \ldepartment \l " shape = "record", style = "rounded" ];
"CLASS" [ label="<CLASS> CLASS|<PK_CLASS>term \l | <F_CLASS> self* \lcourse* \lterm \lsection \lprofessor* \l " shape = "record", style = "rounded" ];
"ENROLLMENT" [ label="<ENROLLMENT> ENROLLMENT|<PK_ENROLLMENT> | <F_ENROLLMENT> self* \lstudent* \lclass* \l " shape = "record", style = "rounded" ];
"SCHEDULE" [ label="<SCHEDULE> SCHEDULE|<PK_SCHEDULE>time \l | <F_SCHEDULE> self* \lclass* \lday \ltime \lroom \l " shape = "record", style = "rounded" ];
"MARK" [ label="<MARK> MARK|<PK_MARK>grade \l | <F_MARK> self* \lenrollment* \lgrade \l " shape = "record", style = "rounded" ];
"STUDENT" [ label="<STUDENT> STUDENT|<PK_STUDENT>snum \l | <F_STUDENT> self* \lsnum \lsname \lyear \l " shape = "record", style = "rounded" ];

// added 
// ---
{ rank = same; STUDENT -> MARK[ style = invis ] }
STUDENT -> ENROLLMENT[ weight = 10, style = invis ]
{ rank = same; ENROLLMENT -> SCHEDULE[ style = invis ]  }
ENROLLMENT -> COURSE[ weight = 10, style = invis ]
// ---
"COURSE":"F_COURSE"->"DEPARTMENT":"PK_DEPARTMENT" [arrowhead = normal] [label="generic label"];
"PROFESSOR":"F_PROFESSOR"->"DEPARTMENT":"PK_DEPARTMENT" [arrowhead = normal] [label="generic label"];
"CLASS":"F_CLASS"->"COURSE":"PK_COURSE" [arrowhead = normal] [label="generic label"];
//extra weight in the line below
"ENROLLMENT":"F_ENROLLMENT"->"CLASS":"PK_CLASS" [arrowhead = normal, label="generic label", weight = 10 ];
//                                                                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^
"SCHEDULE":"F_SCHEDULE"->"CLASS":"PK_CLASS" [arrowhead = normal] [xlabel="generic label"]; // xlabel for better label placement
"MARK":"F_MARK"->"ENROLLMENT":"PK_ENROLLMENT" [arrowhead = normal] [label="generic label"];
}
```

This gives you

[image]

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer - this graph looks great. However, I am generating the above dot code automatically using another program, and cannot really look at the rendering of the graph before adding rank=same to particular nodes. Is there a more automatic way to achieve this look? Perhaps you chose which nodes to rank the same and add invisible edges to based on foreign key declarations?

Comment: Impssible to answer without knowing more about how you are generating the code, but in general, I'd not be overly optimistic. Tweaking tends to need some trial and error, and that seems to be no option in your context. You could generate `rank = same` instructions, but would also need additional invisible edges and, most importantly, weight, which makes it more involved.